# Can't connect Firestore to a Flutter web app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made a "hello world" flutter web project and linked it to my firebase project using the CDN script, and added this line to include firestore:

```
import {getFirestore} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-firestore.js";
```

in my `pubspec.yaml` file I added:

```
firebase_core: 
cloud_firestore:
```

in the `main.dart` file, I did this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

When I launch the app, it just shows the white screen (doesn't load components), and I get this message:

> Error: Assertion failed:
> file:///C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.10.0/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:255:11
> ...
> Application finished.

I also tried `flutterfire configure`, I tried using the script tags instead of CDN within index.html, nothing seems to work. And I've been having this issue for years, it seems like it's just sheer luck that a certain configuration of libraries will actually work together to allow firestore support within flutter web and what that configuration actually is doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Any help would he valued.

I'm on channel stable 3.7.0

Answer (score -1):

I've been building a handful of Flutter web apps that use Firebase recently and I haven't encountered any issues. To make sure you have a clean slate, do the following:

1. Delete `pubspec.lock`
2. Run `flutter clean`
3. Run `flutter pub get`

I would also delete your import statement that uses the CDN. I've never needed that. Instead, just run [flutterfire config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web#add-plugins) and make sure the web option is selected.

Basically, this should work without any complications. You may just have a weird cache or some other obscure issue.

Comment: I agree that it should work. It doesn't. And this issue has been popping up for me over the last 2 years, where you have to mix and match dependencies till you get it to work. It's unscientific. I did try clean and packages get obviously.